# Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element was not found in the project

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

I am testing a SOAP service on through SOAP UI app. I am getting below error when I am running the request -

**Response**

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Fault</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <cause>Transient</cause>
            <code>unknownCode</code>
            <desc>java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element {http://fedex.com/ws/loyalty/v1}GetAccountLoyaltyDetailsRequest was not found in the project</desc>
         </detail>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**GetAccountLoyaltyDetailsRequest** pojo file is already present in the path .

**pojo snippet**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "webAuthenticationDetail",
    "clientDetail",
    "userDetail",
    "transactionDetail",
    "version",
    "applicationId",
    "accountNumber",
    "operatingCompanies"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetAccountLoyaltyDetailsRequest")
public class GetAccountLoyaltyDetailsRequest {
```

Please let me know if any other information is needed . I have googled on this issue ,but could not find any thing helpful .

Also , I have just started using web service . I am trying to add methods to the existing application . i have added all the configuration where the existing was there . Let me know in case this is due to some mismatch .

Thanks in advance,